# How to Add Something Extra to a Busybox System?

Tags: linux, unix, embedded-linux, busybox

So suppose that I have Busybox installed on an embedded device (e.g a router) and need to add something extra to it (a package). Now suppose that now I need to install a package to it besides using the traditional `rpm`. How would I install a package from the Internet similar to what you get using `apt-get` or `apt/aptitude`? Is there a way or a port to `apt-get` or similar for Busybox that I can install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Busybox is really bare-bones and there is no repository. If you want to install something you have to compile it on your own system and copy it to the Busybox system. This requires some skill because the Busybox environment isn't the usual Linux environment, for instance you won't find any of the standard libraries, so you have to build self-contained executables.